# Cloudsearch "OR" query returns fewer results

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm constructing a query with CloudSearch to look at data across a few different fields at once, e.g.

```
csd.search({
  queryParser: "lucene",
  query: "foo:'bar' OR foo2:'bar2' OR foo3:'baz3'",
} cb);
```

This only returns *one* result.  However, if I do `query: "foo:'bar'"` I get back about 50 results. Doing these independently or in smaller groups returns more than one result but it almost seems like this is doing an `AND` instead of an `OR`.

I've also tried using the structured query parser with

```
(or foo:'bar' foo2:'bar2' foo3:'bar3')
```

This returns *four* results.

How can I construct a CloudSearch query to search multiple fields independently of each other?

Comment: You mentioned that `foo:'bar'` returns results. What about `foo2:'bar2'` and `foo3:'bar3'`? Do they behave as expected? Maybe those fields are misconfigured, eg not searchable. I'd also simplify and just debug with `foo` and `foo2`, ignoring `foo3` for now. Your query looks valid (the structured parser one; I'm not familiar with lucene syntax), and I know the `or` operator works so it kinda smells like a configuration issue.

Comment: @alexroussos sorry for not making this clear in the question, but `foo2:'bar2'` and `foo3:'bar3'` alone do return more results. Also combining just two at a time returns more results (but still fewer). Changing the order of the OR also yields different results. All of these fields are `text-array` index fields specifically using the `*` index name syntax (`*_e`).

Comment: @ExplosionPills did you ever find a solution to this, I'm seeing similar unexpected results from OR queries